# Synonym for window.location.href in EL - Get current URL

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, el

I need to get current URL (in javascript `window.location.href`) for value of my `<spring:param>` (in context of creating back URL). For param's value I have to use expression language. Is that even possible, or What are you suggesting? Thank you for answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I need to get current URL (in javascript `window.location.href`)*

It's available by the [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL--).

So, in EL thus just `${pageContext.request.requestURL}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this example does not return stuff behind last "/" .. for instance request params etc.

Comment: `window.location.href` as explicitly mentioned in your question also not. If you're looking for the equivalent of `window.location.search`, then use `HttpServletRequest#getQueryString()`. For all other equivalents, just explore javadoc of `HttpServletRequest` class (click the link in my answer to get there).

Answer (score -3):

It's available by the

[Read This](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL--).

So, in EL thus just ${pageContext.request.requestURL}.

Comment: Why are you after the edit plagiarizing and repeating an already given answer? Just keep the wrong answer deleted.